# How can I check the output of my code using Arduino IDE and ESP8266 when I want to display the data to a large 7-segment LED

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

I have a varying data which is data1, data2, data3 these data changes when there is an update in my database. What I wanted to do is to display these data into 3-layer large 6-digist 7-segment LEDs where data1 is on the 1st layer LED and so on.

For instance, the **data1** = **506070**

This is the data format that I should send to my LED, each layer layer of LED requires 8 bytes:
**5A|FA|00|00|50|60|70| [Checksum(B1+...+B6) (LSB)]**

However in the datasheet each bit has a value (which is in hex)
This is the breakdown for it:

- 1st byte (0x5A) is the header
- 2nd byte (0xFA) is the display address of my LED (here layer 1 is 0xFA)
- 3rd and 4th byte is not that crucial as it is not used just set to (0x00)
- the most important part is the byte 5,6,7 these are the ones being displayed on my LED (0x50, 0x60, 0x70).
- last byte is the checksum which is the sum of the 2nd byte till the 6th byte and multiplied to the least significant byte
  **[(B1+B2+B3+B4+B6+B6) (LSB)]**

So my question is, how can I code the data1,data2,data3 in my ESP to display the data1 to LED 1st layer, data2 to LED 2nd layer and data3 to LED 3rd layer?
I am using Arduino IDE to code my ESP.

Here is the sample of my connections: https://imgtr.ee/images/2023/04/17/yHVsY.png 1

- **note**: The LEDS are daisy-chained and are connected over RS485 cable, that is why I will use MAX485 transceiver module so that the ESP can display the data to the LEDs.

Any inputs about this question is appreciated.

I have not yet tested this code but I will be using this to implement the display of data. I am confused with the bit shifting here and not sure if this is correct syntax when I store my data1 to byte4-byte6.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const int data1 = 506070;

// Set up the UART interface
SoftwareSerial uart(11, 12);
const int BAUD_RATE = 9600;

// Set up the digital output pins for the MAX485 transceiver
const int DE_PIN = 10; 
const int RE_PIN = 14;  

void setup() {
  // Set up the UART interface
  uart.begin(BAUD_RATE);

  // Set up the digital output pins for the MAX485 transceiver
  pinMode(DE_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RE_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // Set the MAX485 to transmit mode
  digitalWrite(DE_PIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RE_PIN, HIGH);

  // Define the data to send to the LED display
  uint8_t header = 0x5A; // byte 0
  uint8_t address = 0xFA; // byte 1
  uint8_t byte2 = 0x00;
  uint8_t byte3 = 0x00;
  uint8_t byte4 = data1 & 0x5A;
  uint8_t byte5 = (data1 >> 8) & 0x5A;
  uint8_t byte6 = (data1 >> 16) & 0x5A;
  uint8_t checksum = header + address + byte2 + byte3 + byte4 + byte5 + byte6;
  checksum = checksum & 0x5A;  // Keep only the lower 8 bits

  // Send the data over the UART interface
  uart.write(header);
  uart.write(address);
  uart.write(byte2);
  uart.write(byte3);
  uart.write(byte4);
  uart.write(byte5);
  uart.write(byte6);
  uart.write(checksum);

  // Set the MAX485 to receive mode
  digitalWrite(DE_PIN, LOW);
  digitalWrite(RE_PIN, LOW);

  delay(1000);  // Wait for a second before sending the next command
}
```

Comment: If you have a decimal value of `506070` called `data`, `data1 >> 8` is 1976, `data1 >> 16` is 7. I think it is not what you want.  Even if you means it to be `0x506070`, both `(data1 >> 8) & 0x5A` and `(data1 >> 16) & 0x5A` would be `1`.  BTW, what is the purpose of `& 0x5A`?

Comment: sorry for the late reply but I have edited the code and is now working:

uint8_t  byte4 = data2 % 100;

uint8_t  byte5 = (data2 / 100) % 100;

uint8_t  byte6 = (data2 / 10000) % 100;

I used this instead and is now displaying the value that I want to get by triyng the serial print:

Serial.print("address   (Hex): ");

Serial.println(address, HEX);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to display the bytes correctly on th 7 segment displays.

Start by writing a method that has the ID of the display and the data bytes as inputs.
It should do the following steps:

1.) Take the last significant byte

2.) Combine a copy of the byte input with a logical AND with 15 (0000 1111)

3.) Send the result to the last significant 7 Segment display

4.) Take the last significant byte

5.) Combine the byte with a logical AND with 240 (1111 0000)

6.) Do a bitshift on the resulting byte by 4 (byte >> 4)

7.) Send the result to the second to the next 7 segment display

8.) Start over by 1.) with the next byte and write to the next part of the 7 segment display

[Here is how i came up with the numbers 15 and 240 to do the logical AND and also where the bitshift comes from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IenO.png)

Comment: Yes I wanted to display this bytes as this is the data format of the large LED.

{ 0x5A, 0xAB, 0x00, 0x00, 0x50, 0x60, 0x70 [ checksum(B1+...+B6)(LSB) ] } if I have this data format, is the last significant byte the right-most byte which is 0x70? I am using Arduino IDE to code this.

May I ask what is the purpose of bitshift?

Comment: Yes you start from the right (0x70) because then you can use a for-loop and count up. If you would start from the left you would have to count down.

Comment: With the logical AND you create a stencil for the byte. The first time you use it, you get back only the first half byte that you can send to the display.
The second time you get a full byte (0x70 AND 240 = 0x70). You set the second half of the byte to 0. Since you only want to send the 7 to the display yout would have to remove it compleatly. So you shift the bits and end up with 0x07. Now xou can send the 7 to your display.

Comment: But as i am writing that i realized that the whole operation can be simplifyed. You dont have to do the logical AND the second time, since you are already cutting out the lower halfbyte with the bitshift.
So you only have to do the logical and to get the lower half and the bitshift to get the upper half of the byte.

Comment: The bit 0 is the left most so it means that my 0xFF is the LSB and 0x70 is the MSB as it is the bit 7. So the bit shifting is needed whenever I try to output the data the first byte to the LED? Why is the step 2 where my LSB need to have logical AND with 15, and on step 5 why is the LSB again be AND with 240?

Comment: I have updated my post @Colebam for some clarification about my question.